# Why i need google appengine to create my own chatbot fow my own youtube live stream?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, youtube, chatbot, youtube-livestreaming-api

I trying to make my own chatbot that can skip tracks when see !skip in chat, on twitch im easy done it, but on youtube it so hard! Why i need something like google-cloud-api or google-app-engine?! i just want to get messages from the chat and sometimes send messages.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: because Google requires you to. It is their API, they get to make up the rules.

Besides, it is a *very* common practice to only let authenticated users access an API, even for read-only access. For write access (e.g. post chat messages) any decent service will require you to authenticate yourself.